# Azure DevOps - Where is my custom version counter variable stored?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, version, counter, azure-pipelines

I have a Azure Pipeline file azure-pipelines.yml which is run by my Azure Linux agent. Next I have a variable myBuildCounter defined which is increased by a counter. The value of the variable myBuildCounter is saved during builds and its value reused, even though I didn't create any variables in the Azure interface. Does someone knows where the variable value is stored in Azure? Thanks in advance.

Definition of variable

```
variables:
  myBuildCounter: $[counter(variables['myBuildCounter'], 0)]
```

Usage of variable

```
task: PowerShell@2
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
          Write-Host "Build version: $env:MYBUILDCOUNTER"
        failOnStderr: true
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you have defined this Pipeline variable at the root level in the yaml file.

This will make it available to all jobs and stages in the pipeline and is a global variable. Global variables defined in a YAML are not visible in the pipeline settings UI.

Variables at the job level override variables at the root and stage level. Variables at the stage level override variables at the root level.

Refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#set-variables-in-pipeline) document for more details.